# How do I use polar coördinates in order to integrate along a curved axis?

Tags: polar-coordinates

Currently I'm struggeling with a mechanics problem. My issue is not the mechanics, but the mathematics. Therefore I see it fit to post this question here.

I need to integrate along the axis of the beam and I need to do this in polor coordinates. This is where I get stuck. I know from calculus that I need to express the x and y value in an angle in combination with a geometric function.

It looks like this beam is the quarter of a circle. I think this piece of data is usefull, but I don't know how to proceed.

Question: How do I integrate along the axis of this beam in polor coordinates?

[image]

Comment: What integral specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: The first calculation I need to find the moment distribution. I see that this is still the force x horizontal length. When I have an expression for the moment distribution I need to intergrate that expression along the axis to find the stored strain energy @MarkSaving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How do I use polar coördinates in order to integrate along a curved axis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057031/how-do-i-use-polar-co%c3%b6rdinates-in-order-to-integrate-along-a-curved-axis)

I've flipped your sketch left to right.
Let $A=(a,0)$ and $B=(0,a).$ In polar coordinates,
$x=a\cos \theta,$ $y=a\sin \theta$ and $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi\over 2$ radians. For example,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} a\, d\theta$$
gives the length of your beam.